# How to adjust the size of the checkerboard pattern with imshowpair on MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I wrote the following code:

```
imageResult = imshowpair(brain1, brain2,'checkerboard');
```

But this does not control the checkerboard size.

How can I specify what should the checkerboard square size be?
The `imshowpair` doc is not clear on that.
If you know a different way , please feel free to suggest it as well!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is an option to do that automatically.

But you can create a checkerboard index manually using the kronecker tensor product.

```
ind = kron(eye(2,2),ones(5,5))
```

produce a 2x2 checkerboard with a grid size of 5:

```
   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1
   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1
   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1
   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1
   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1
```

You can now duplicate this pattern N times.

For example we duplicate this pattern 10 times.

```
ind = kron(ones(10,10),ind)
```

> If your images are 3D images, you can still replicate this matrix 3 times:
>
> ```
> ind = repmat(ind,1,1,3);
> ```

So you obtain a `2X5X10 x 2X5X10` `(500x500)` checkerboard matrice

Now you can combine your two images, that need also need to be 500x500:

```
IMG1 = IMG1(logical(ind)) = 0  % an index need to be of type logical.
IMG2 = IMG1(logical(~ind)) = 0

IMG = IMG1+IMG2
```

If it's impossible to get a checkerboard matrice of the right size because your images have an odd number of columns or lines your can always take a sample of the original matrice

```
subind = ind(1:size(IMG1,1),1:size(IMG1,2))
```

> Same thing for 3D index:
>
> ```
> subind = ind(1:size(IMG1,1),1:size(IMG1,2),:)
> ```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `checkerboard` function to generate a checkerboard in the appropriate size. e.g.

```
I = checkerboard(5);
```

will make a square checkerboard where each square is 5*5. You can further adjust the input to also make it rectangular, e.g. if you want a 5x8 checkerboard instead of an 8x8 checkerboard

```
I = checkerboard(5,5,8);
```

Note: if you want a binary checkerboard just adjust the command with

```
I = checkerboard(5)>0.5;
```